# How to compare items in lists for a battleship game

Tags: python

I am trying to build a simple battleship program with python using lists and loops, but I am unsure of how to determine if I hit the enemy ship or not. I am new to python and hopefully I can get some help on how I could make my program work. Much thanks!

The code at the very bottom is how I try to determine if a ship is attacked or not.

```
import time

print("WELCOME TO BATTLE SHIP!\n")

player1board = [["A", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["B", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["C", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["D", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["E","o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

player2board = [["A", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["B", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["C", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["D", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["E","o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

player1attack = [["A", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["B", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["C", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["D", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["E","o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

player2attack = [["A", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["B", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["C", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["D", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], ["E","o", "o", "o", "o", "o"], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

turn = 0
coord1p1 = 0
coord2p1 = 0
coord1p2 = 0
coord2p2 = 0
coord1 = 0
coord2 = 0

def boatPlacement():
    if (turn % 2) == 1:
        print("Player 1, please place your boat\n")
        for i in range(len(player1board)):
            for j in range(len(player1board[i])):
                print(player1board[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        print("\n")
        coord1p1x = input("Coord 1 (A, B, C, D, E): ")
        while True:
            if coord1p1x == "A":
                coord1p1x = 0
                break
            elif coord1p1x == "B":
                coord1p1x = 1
                break
            elif coord1p1x == "C":
                coord1p1x = 2
                break
            elif coord1p1x == "D":
                coord1p1x = 3
                break
            elif coord1p1x == "E":
                coord1p1x = 4
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input!\n")
                coord1p1x = input("Coord 1 (A, B, C, D, E): ")
        global coord2p1
        coord2p1 = input("Coord 2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): ")
        print("\n")
        while True:
            if coord2p1 == "1":
                coord2p1 = int(coord2p1)
                break
            elif coord2p1 == "2":
                coord2p1 = int(coord2p1)
                break
            elif coord2p1 == "3":
                coord2p1 = int(coord2p1)
                break
            elif coord2p1 == "4":
                coord2p1 = int(coord2p1)
                break
            elif coord2p1 == "5":
                coord2p1 = int(coord2p1)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input!\n")
                coord2p1 = input("Coord 2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): ")
        global coord1p1
        coord1p1 = coord1p1x
        player1board[coord1p1][coord2p1] = "*"
        for i in range(len(player1board)):
            for j in range(len(player1board[i])):
                print(player1board[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        player1board[coord1p1][coord2p1] = "x"
        print("\n")
        
    elif (turn % 2) == 0:
        print("Player 2, please place your boat\n")
        for i in range(len(player2board)):
            for j in range(len(player2board[i])):
                print(player2board[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        print("\n")
        coord1p2x = input("Coord 1 (A, B, C, D, E): ")
        while True:
            if coord1p2x == "A":
                coord1p2x = 0
                break
            elif coord1p2x == "B":
                coord1p2x = 1
                break
            elif coord1p2x == "C":
                coord1p2x = 2
                break
            elif coord1p2x == "D":
                coord1p2x = 3
                break
            elif coord1p2x == "E":
                coord1p2x = 4
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input!\n")
                coord1p2x = input("Coord 1 (A, B, C, D, E): ")
        global coord2p2
        coord2p2 = input("Coord 2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): ")
        while True:
            if coord2p2 == "1":
                coord2p2 = int(coord2p2)
                break
            elif coord2p2 == "2":
                coord2p2 = int(coord2p2)
                break
            elif coord2p2 == "3":
                coord2p2 = int(coord2p2)
                break
            elif coord2p2 == "4":
                coord2p2 = int(coord2p2)
                break
            elif coord2p2 == "5":
                coord2p2 = int(coord2p2)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input!\n")
                coord2p2 = input("Coord 2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): ")
        global coord1p2
        coord1p2 = coord1p2x
        print("\n")
        player2board[coord1p2][coord2p2] = "*"
        for i in range(len(player2board)):
            for j in range(len(player2board[i])):
                print(player2board[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        player2board[coord1p2][coord2p2] = "x"

def turnSwitch():
    global turn
    turn = turn + 1
    return turn

def whosTurn():
    global turn
    if (turn % 2) == 1:
        print("\nPlayer 1's turn")
    else:
        print("\nPlayer 2's turn")

def screenWipe():
    t = 0
    while t < 20:
        print("")
        t = t+1
        
def attack():
    print("\nWhere would you like to attack?")
    coordx = input("Coord 1 (A, B, C, D, E): ")
    global coord2
    coord2 = int(input("Coord 2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): "))
    if coordx == "A":
        coordx = 0
    elif coordx == "B":
        coordx = 1
    elif coordx == "C":
        coordx = 2
    elif coordx == "D":
        coordx = 3
    elif coordx == "E":
        coordx = 4
    else:
        print("invalid coord!")
    global coord1
    coord1 = coordx
        
    if (turn % 2) == 1: 
        player1attack[coord1][coord2] = "x"
        for i in range(len(player1attack)):
            for j in range(len(player1attack[i])):
                print(player1attack[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        print("Switching turns!")
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        player2attack[coord1][coord2] = "x"
        for i in range(len(player2attack)):
            for j in range(len(player2attack[i])):
                print(player2attack[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
        print("Switching turns!")
        time.sleep(5)

turnSwitch()
boatPlacement()
screenWipe()
time.sleep(3)
turnSwitch()
boatPlacement()
screenWipe()
i = 1

while (i < 99999):
    turnSwitch()
    whosTurn()
    attack()
    if (player1attack[coord1][coord2] == player2board[coord1p2][coord2p2]):
        print("\nPlayer 1 wins!")
        print(player1attack[coord1][coord2])
        print(player2board[coord1p2][coord2p2])
        break
    
    elif (player2attack[coord1][coord2] == player1board[coord1p1][coord2p1]):
        print("\nPlayer 2 wins!")
        break
    
    else:
        screenWipe()
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: This is very hard to read. Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

**IF THIS IS SINGLE PLAYER**

What you could do is `import random` module in order to get the `randint` command. You can then basically try to make it so that randint randomly chooses a spot on your board (said spot being the index of the row and index of the column). Then you could save that those index coordinates to a variable. To check if the player hit the ship, see what index coordinates they picked and see if they match up with the randomly generated index coordinates.

**IF THIS IS MULTIPLAYER**
If this is multiplayer, then the principles would be the same. However, instead of using `randint` to generate coordinates, the player would choose where they place their ship (since that's how the game works).

P.S.
The format of randint is `randint(lowest, highest)` which will pick a number from the lowest to highest number specified.

To import it you do:

```
from random import randint
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving to much code, it is messy and hard to find the solution. I see you are using nested lists to represent the table. So to get a value of it you need to use this line of code: `player1board[0][1]` first number is the index of all lists (outer list) which can be used for rows, and the second number is the element in the inner list, which can be used for columns. So you can use it like this:

```
row = int(input('Row: '))
column = int(input('Column: '))
player1board[row - 1][column - 1]
# I'm using the "-1" because when user inputs row number 1 it's actually index of 0
```

And you can then check if the value is equal to the value of the boat on that place

Edit: I just noticed that at the end you are using while `(1 < 99999)`. You can use a simple `while True` which will run forever and then to exit the loop use `break`.